# Geometric interpretation of the non-uniqueness of the solution of a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, geometric-interpretation

> Show that the equation $$\pmatrix{3&-7&0\\2&2&5\\1&3&4}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = \pmatrix{3\\2\\1}$$ does not have a unique solution, and give a geometrical interpretation.

---

Now, the first part of the question is fairly straightforward. I've shown that the determinant of the 3x3 matrix is 0; and thus the system of equation does not have a unique solution.

After that, I've rewritten the matrices into a set of linear equations.
$\begin{cases}3x-7y+0z=3\\2x+2y+5z=2\\
x+3y+4z=1\end{cases}$

Now this is where I'm slightly stumped, I've attempted this part of the  question but have no idea if I'm correct.

Through eliminating $x$ from pairs of equations, I've gotten $-4y-3z =0$ from 2 pairs and $-16y-22z=0$ from the other. What does this mean exactly?

Comment: "Does not have unique solution" could mean "has no solution" or "has infinitely many solutions".  Then the geometric meaning would be either: "these three planes in $3$-space have no point in common", or "these three planes in $3$-space intersect in a line".

Comment: There is no $z$ in the first. If you try and solve the last two by eliminating $z$, you get the first equation. So these planes do not intersect in a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three planes pass through the same line $r$ of equation
$$
r:\begin{cases}
3 x-7 y-3=0\\
4 y+3 z=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

---

[image]